# How to delete the current and previous line at the same time on vi?

Tags: linux, vi

Is there a command to delete the current and previous line at the same time in vi? I have tried **:-1,d** but it won't work.

Comment: In command mode, type `k2dd`

Answer (score 4):

In normal mode, press <kbd>d</kbd> for delete. Then, press <kbd>k</kbd> for upward motion. This is a shorthand for <kbd>d1k</kbd>. You can increase the count to delete more than the current and previous line. For example, to delete the current line and the previous *two* lines, type <kbd>d2k</kbd>.

In general, most commands take motion and count modifiers. See the following Vim documentation for details:

> The motion commands can be used after an operator command, to have the command
> operate on the text that was moved over.  That is the text between the cursor
> position before and after the motion.  Operators are generally used to delete
> or change text.  The following operators are available:
>
> ...
>
> If the motion includes a count and the operator also had a count before it,
> the two counts are multiplied.  For example: "2d3w" deletes six words.

[Motions and operators](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
-2dd
```

should achieve what you require. This will move up one line and then perform dd on 2 lines.

Comment: It should be useful to point out that this works in normal mode (i.e. don't start with `:`), because the OPs example is not in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it as a : command then

```
.,-1d
```

works for me